# Group in Python regex substitution

Tags: python, regex

Why does this code return `'static PyObject*\npy_\x00(void)\n{'`? I thought it should look for the first group and replace it. Also, I don't see where the `\x00` comes from.

```
re.sub(r'def\s+([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\s*\(\s*\):',r'static PyObject*\npy_\0(void)\n{','def myfunc():')
```

Comment: I think x00 comes from \0

Comment: uhhhh... more context?

Comment: try changing `\0` to `\1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the example copied from the [docs for re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), except you changed one piece.
You have:

```
r'static PyObject*\npy_\0(void)\n{'
```

It should be (use \1 for the first group):

```
r'static PyObject*\npy_\1(void)\n{'
```

When you use `\0`, that is interpreted as the escape for null `\x00`. If you really want group 0 (the entire substring matched by the re), you need to use `\g<0>`.

Answer (score 0):

`\0` does not reference the matched pattern.  It should be `\g<0>`

```
r'static PyObject*\npy_\g<0>(void)\n{'
```

This results in

```
static PyObject*\npy_def myfunc():(void)\n{
```

If you want to replace the first captured group, you could use `\g<1>`, but `\1` will also work.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it should look for the first group and replace it.

It doesn't. Python's `re.sub` doesn't look for the first group and replace it, it replaces the entire matched pattern. It's up to you to group and re-insert the parts you want to keep.